# Building an App for clubs. Am I violating google-play policy by using 3rd party methods in the app for payment to increase the number of members ?

Tags: android, paypal, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am building an Android app for clubs (such as Rotary and others). Using the App, club President and Directors can send out information to all the members and members can view the information. The App is free for both President/Director and Members. Users can use the same app for accessing multiple clubs. For clubs with less than 30 members there is no charge. For clubs with more members, we plan to charge a nominal fee for adding more members.

1. The clubs can pay us by cheque for additional members
2. They can pay online through our website
3. They can increase members from within the app by making payment using the facility provided within the app

My Questions:

1. For option 3 above, do I have to use necessarily google’s payment module or can I integrate a 3rd party gateway such as paypal ? (The app will be on google play store.)
2. If I don’t have option 3, but collect payment through option 1 and 2, Am I violating any of the google’s in-app purchase policies?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: reading your question.. it looks ok to use external payment integration. Read 1st paragraph in policy document https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/, if you feel any of your scenario is in 1st paragraph use google payment gateway